# OnDeviceReady event is not available inside phonegap.js and cordova.js Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I have installed phonegap using npm- install -g phonegap , but when i open phonegap.js and 
cordova.js, I dont find any OndeviceReady() Event inside these js files.and when I reference these js on my code.. Event not fired... I am working on phonegap for Windows Phone. Please Help.
my code is:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();

        function onDeviceReady()  
           {
            document.getElementById("deviceName").innerHTML = device.name;
            document.getElementById("version").innerHTML = device.phonegap;
            document.getElementById("mobilePlatform").innerHTML = device.platform;
            document.getElementById("platformVersion").innerHTML = device.version;
            document.getElementById("uuid").innerHTML = device.uuid;

            alert("I am ready to going!");
        }
        function init() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
 <body onload="init()">
 <h1>Device Info</h1> 
 <table> 
 <tr> 
 <td>Device Name</td> 
<td id="deviceName"></td> 
 </tr> 
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a function to add the Eventlistener. Just add the eventlistener

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    app.initialize();
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady(), false);

    function onDeviceReady()  
       {
        alert("I am ready to going!");
        document.getElementById("deviceName").innerHTML = device.name;
        document.getElementById("version").innerHTML = device.phonegap;
        document.getElementById("mobilePlatform").innerHTML = device.platform;
        document.getElementById("platformVersion").innerHTML = device.version;
        document.getElementById("uuid").innerHTML = device.uuid;


    }


    }
</script>
</head>
```